# Seeking free/open source Western Australian Topographical data?

Tags: topography, data, australia

Does anyone know (or have m) a free or open source Western Australian Topographical datasets?

I have a project that involves terrain relief in Northam, ideally they want it at a scale of 1;25,000 but i thought i would ask around if anyone knew (or had) a dataset before buying one from landgate.

Comment: You might have better luck posting this inquiry over at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange. Have you already looked over what's available through open license from the department of Natural Resources?

Answer (score 1):

I found a free [DEM extractor](http://www.ga.gov.au/elvis) based out of Geoscience Australia and used the DEM to create contours via the contour tool in ArcGIS Desktop.